# Scraping Data after filling form in python of a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have tried to scrape data from **http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/** with python and BeautifulSoup.

Firstly, website need to fill the form. After filling the form the website provide results. I have attached two image here.

Before Submitting Form: https://prnt.sc/w4lo7i

After Submission: https://prnt.sc/w4lqd0

I have tried with following code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

resultdata = {
'sr': '3',
'et': '2',
'exam': 'ssc',
'year': 2012,
'board': 'chittagong',
'roll': 102275,
'reg': 626948,
'button2': 'Submit',
 }
headers ={
    'user-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': 'PHPSESSID=24vp2g7ll9utu1p2ob5bniq263; tcount_unique_eb_log=1',
    'Origin': 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd',
    'Referer': 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/',
    'Request URL': 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/result.php'
    
    
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.content,'html5lib')
#Scraping  and by passing Captcha

alltable =soup.findAll('td')
captcha = alltable[56].text.split('+')
for digit in captcha:
   value_one, value_two = int(captcha[0]), int(captcha[1])

resultdata['value_s'] = value_one+value_two
r=s.post(url, data=resultdata, headers= headers)
```

While printing r.content it is showing first page's code. I want to scrape the second page.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: when I put i nthe info, I only get 1 page. I don't see where there's a second page

Answer (score 0):

You are making post requests to the wrong url. Moreover, you are supposed to add the value of two numbers and use the result right next to `value_s`. If you are using bs4 version 3.7 or later, the following selector will work for you as I've used pseudo css selector. The bottom line is your issue is solved. Try the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/'
result_url = 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/result.php'

resultdata = {
    'sr': '3',
    'et': '2',
    'exam': 'ssc',
    'year': 2012,
    'board': 'chittagong',
    'roll': 102275,
    'reg': 626948,
    'button2': 'Submit',
 }

def get_number(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html5lib")
    num = 0
    captcha_numbers = soup.select_one("tr:has(> td > #value_s) > td + td").text.split("+")
    for i in captcha_numbers:
        num+=int(i)
    return num

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'
    resultdata['value_s'] = get_number(s,link)
    r = s.post(result_url, data=resultdata)
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

resultdata = {
'sr': '3',
'et': '2',
'exam': 'ssc',
'year': "2012",
'board': 'chittagong',
'roll': "102275",
'reg': "626948",

 }
headers ={
    'user-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': 'PHPSESSID=24vp2g7ll9utu1p2ob5bniq263; tcount_unique_eb_log=1',
    'Origin': 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd',
    'Referer': 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/',
    'Request URL': 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/result.php'


}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/index.php'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
    # print(soup.prettify())
#Scraping  and by passing Captcha

    alltable =soup.findAll('td')
    captcha = alltable[56].text.split('+')
    print(captcha)
    value_one, value_two = int(captcha[0]), int(captcha[1])
    print(value_one, value_one)

    resultdata['value_s'] = value_one+value_two

    resultdata['button2'] = 'Submit'
    print(resultdata)
    r=s.post("http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd/result.php", data=resultdata, headers= headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    print(soup.prettify())
```